# What's the correct phrase to use? In our app or on our app

Tags: grammaticality, phrases

This new service will be available in our app.

This new service will be available on our app.

What's correct? Second one feels wrong but interested to know what's right here.

Comment: I would tend to use "in" here, but a right/wrong feels awfully subjective.

Comment: 1) *This new service will* ***come with*** *our app.* 2) *Our app will provide this new service.*

Answer (score -1):

Both of these phrases work for the intended purpose. "On our app" is probably the more common phraseology, and sounds a bit less clunky, though the message would not be impacted either way by the use of either of the phrases. The distinction here is nonexistent, and in other places so subtle that many languages (such as Spanish) don't even have separate words for the expressions.

Comment: This strikes me as being completely backwards and incorrect. I would unflinchingly say that _in_ is vastly more common than _on_ in this context. I don’t recall ever hearing or seeing _on_ used in this way. If you’re giving the **name** of an app which functions as a platform, then _on_ is perfectly natural, but that’s because _on_ goes with platforms: on Twitter, on Instagram, on Tinder, etc. But you’d never edit an image \*on Photoshop or read a book \*on iBooks.

Comment: I have exactly the same feeling as @JanusBahsJacquet. "On" only feels right with the name of the app or company. The "in" seems way more common to me when referring to an abstract "an app".

Comment: From a quick search, the preposition seems to depend on context: sources talk about "swipe up on the app" or "contact us on the app" but "features in the app". I guess this corresponds to a physical vs more abstract sense.